# "Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached" error

Tags: linq-to-sql, listbox, windows-phone-7.1, delete-row

I have two tables: `Main` and `Vendors`.

```
Main table:
MainID (PK)
Name
Address
...

Vendors table:
VendorID (PK)
MainID (ForeignKey)
Code
....
```

The data from the `Vendors` table is displayed into a `ListBox` control.

When I try to delete a row from the `Vendors` table, using a button in the ListBox control, I get the following error:

> **Cannot remove an entity that has not been attached.**

The Delete button code is:

```
        Dim button = TryCast(sender, Button)
    If button IsNot Nothing Then
        Using db As New theContext.theContext("Data Source=isostore:/theDB.sdf")
            Dim RecordToDelete As Vendors = TryCast(button.DataContext, Vendors)

            VendorsRecords.Remove(RecordToDelete)

            db.VendorsRecords.DeleteOnSubmit(RecordToDelete)

            db.SubmitChanges()
        End Using
    End If
```

Comment: I get the error at the line: _db.VendorsRecords.DeleteOnSubmit(RecordToDelete)_

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
db.VendorsRecords.Attach(RecordtoDelete)
```

before the line that is giving you an error.

You are getting this error because the db context doesn't know about the record you are trying to delete.

Comment: I did and I get this error: 'An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext.  This is not supported.' at the new added line.

Comment: Return new error: Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use.